# Vectorize index set building

Tags: matlab, vectorization

I need to build a cell array of indices. Each cell contains all indices corresponding to a unique value of `ori` in the following code:

```
oriVals = unique(ori);
oriIndicies = cell(numel(oriVals), 1);
for kOri = 1:numel(oriVals)
    oriIndicies{kOri} = find(ori == oriVals(kOri));
end
```

Can I write this more compactly with MATLAB's native functions? I just want to make sure there isn't any before I write my own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
oriIndicies = cell(numel(oriVals), 1);
for kOri = 1:numel(oriVals)
    oriIndicies{kOri} = find(ori == oriVals(kOri));
end
```

you may write:

```
oriIndicies = arrayfun(@(x) find(ori == x), oriVals, 'UniformOutput', false);
```

but be careful, `oriIndicies` is now a row, not a column. Also, this is almost for sure slower than your `for` loop with memory allocation, because evaluating anonymous functions is slow.

Comment: Cool. Thanks for the warnings as well.

Comment: Perhaps it's more compact, but it'll definitely take longer to run.